# Request user to sign state changing transaction with metamask using Infura and web3js

Tags: web3js, metamask, infura, raw-transaction, react

Can't seem to find the right function to ask the user to sign a transaction via metamask, this is my code so far:

```
  const bet = '102500000000000010'
  const account = '0xc8133b744147078a551b8d9c547414d427d8f579'

  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, function (err, nonce) {
    const data = Contract.methods.payBet(1553399554260556, bet).encodeABI();
    const tx = new Tx({
      nonce,
      gasPrice: 165335,
      gasLimit: 100000,
      to: "0x232b....",
      value: bet,
      data,
    })

    //THIS tx.sign SHOULD BE THE METAMASK PART, since I dont have the user PK
    tx.sign(ethereumjs.Buffer.Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

    var raw = '0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, function (err, transactionHash) {
      console.log(transactionHash);
    });
  });
```

What should I do to ask the user to sign the tx? I also tried to use web3.eth.sendTransaction but it is not supported by infura.

I'm abit lost here

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) instead of `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` and Metamask will ask user to sign your transaction, and then will send signed transaction to Infura.  See [Metamask FAQ](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dancers-we-handle-user-authorization) for more details.

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: Yes, Infura does not support it, but Metamask will translate your `sendTransaction` call into `sendSignedTransaction` call.  See the following link: https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dancers-we-handle-user-authorization

Comment: Ok, but then I get this error "The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available" calling web3.eth.sendTransaction

Comment: Then you are probably using Web3 API provider from Web3.js rather than the one provided by Metamask.  Check this link for details: https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check